# Using pandas value_counts() under defined condition

Tags: python, pandas

After a lot of errors, exceptions and high blood pressure, I finally came up with this solution that works for what I needed it to: basically I need to calculate all the column values that respect a specific condition.

So, let's say I got a list of strings just like

```
vehicle = ['car', 'boat', 'car', 'car', 'bike', 'tank', 'DeLorean', 'tank']
```

I want to count which values appear more than 2 times.

Consider that the column name of the dataframe based upon the list is 'veh'.

So, this piece of code works:

```
df['veh'].value_counts()[df['veh'].value_counts() > 2]
```

The question is: why the `[df['veh'].value_counts() > 2]` part comes right after the "()" of `value_counts()`? No "." or any other linking sign that could mean something.

If I use the code

```
df['classi'].value_counts() > 1
```

(which would be the logic synthax that my limited brain can abstract), it returns boolean values.

Can someone, please, help me understanding the logic behind pandas?

I am pretty sure that pandas is awesome and the problem lies on this side of mine, but I really want to understand it. I've read a lot of material (documentation included), but could not find a solution to this gap of mine.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you also read [this part](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line of code

```
df['veh'].value_counts()
```

Return a pandas Series with keys as indices and number of occurrences as values

Everything between square brackets [] are filters on keys for a pandas Series. So

```
df['veh'].value_counts()['car']
```

Should return the number of occurrences of the word 'car' in column 'veh'. Which is equivalent to the corresponding value for key 'car' on the series `df['veh'].value_counts()`

A pandas series also accept lists of keys as indices, So

```
df['veh'].value_counts()[['car','boat']]
```

Should return the number of occurrences for the words 'car' and 'boat' respectively

Furthermore, the series accept a list of booleans as key, if it is of the same length of the series. That is, it accepts a **boolean mask**

When you write

```
df['veh'].value_counts() > 2
```

You make a comparison between each value on `df['veh'].value_counts()` and the number 2. This returns a boolean for each value, that is a **boolean mask**.

So you can use the boolean mask as a filter on the series you created. Thus

```
df['veh'].value_counts()[df['veh'].value_counts() > 2]
```

Returns all the occurrences for the keys where the occurrences are greater than 2

Comment: So If I am not mistaken, the second part of the code works like some kind of "parameter". The first part defines what will be calculated based upon the second part., i.e , the second part brings all the booleans defined by ">2" and the first part counts this booleans. Is this correct?

Comment: What you call the first part and the second part?

df['veh'].value_counts() computes the number of occurrences for each value in 'veh' and returns it as a series, which is similar to a list of tuples

df['veh'].value_counts() > 2 computes if each value has more than two occurrences, it returns a list of booleans

there's no code counting booleans, the booleans just filter the output of df['veh'].value_counts()

Answer (score 1):

The logic is that you can slice a series with a boolean series of the same size:

```
s[bool_series]
```

or equivalently

```
s.loc[bool_series]
```

This is also referred as [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Now, your code is equivalent to:

```
s = df['veh'].value_counts()

bool_series = s > 2
```

And then either the first two lines, e.g. `s[s>2]`

Comment: Ok, but why will pandas crash if the so called bool series would be based upon a matching comparison?if instead of [df['veh'].value_counts() > 2] I use [df['veh'] == 'car'] it will not work.